# How to check if string exists in more than X rows

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if the following is possible, and how:

I want to check if a username in my table appears in 5 or more rows

my table:

[image]

Example of usage that I want:

If the name (teste) is on more than 5 rows then do something..

Comment: what have you tried so far? You could simply do a count in your MYSQL query and find if the username exists in more than 5 rows. select count(*) from tbl where username = 'user'

Comment: thats the thing, I don't want to compare names, I want it to search it ANY name exists in more than 5 rows

Comment: Then you simply write another query like this select count(username),username from tbl group by username and if the count is higher than 5 then it exists more than 5 times.

Comment: Which API are you using to connect with?

Comment: try sth like this [ SELECT yt.name, COUNT(yt.name) as noOfOccurance from yourTableName as yt GROUP BY yt.name HAVING COUNT(yt.name) > 5 ; ]

Comment: what is the yt supose to be?

Comment: *Which API are you using to connect with? –  Fred -ii- 7 mins ago*

Comment: I'm not using any api

Comment: So, just phpmyadmin, no PHP whatsoever. You need to know what an API is.

Comment: why would I need an api???

Comment: Never mind. I know what you're using now as the ***MySQL API*** you are connecting with. The 2 comments I asked you.

Comment: Please stop updating your question with code given from an answer given below. I did a rollback to your original post.

Comment: Im still a noob, calm the f*** down big boy

Comment: *"Im still a noob, calm the f*** down big boy –  Joao Paulo 31 secs ago"* - You can do that yourself. Don't be an idiot, or I'll flag your sorry ass.

Comment: You didn't have to answer like that just saying, not everyone has your knowledge and I think you know that

Comment: Oh, I had the answer alright, to your question that is. But you were busy with the other guy, which I didn't want to tramp over their answer. I do have respect for people who spend time trying to help someone. So next time, don't overwrite your question with code supplied from answers; Stack doesn't like that. You can take it up with the moderators/creators. They built it, not me.

Comment: Plus, really.... *"Please stop updating your question with code given from an answer given below. I did a rollback to your original post."* - What's so bad about that comment anyway? You are just too sensitive. Your comment about having me "calm the f*** down", wow; *rich*.

Comment: sorry but you asked all that before and just ignored even after you got the question, but whatever I got the "stop updating your question with code given from an answer given bellow" part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HAVING, it allows you to filter by aggregated / manipulated fields

```
SELECT count(username) as shows_counter from tbl 
group by username 
HAVING count(username)>5


$check = mysql_query("SELECT count(name),name 
FROM hack_log group by name HAVING count(name)>5"); 

$check = mysql_num_rows($result);// **Add this row**

if($check){ echo "HACKER!"; }else{ echo "not hacker"; }
```

- Please use PDO or mysqli build-in objects

### Accorging to your needs

You need to check number of rows

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=your_hostname;dbname=your_db;charset=UTF-8', $user, $pass);
    $q = $db->prepare('SELECT count(name),name 
    FROM hack_log group by name HAVING count(name)>5');
    $q->execute();
    $rows = $q->fetchAll();

   $res= count($rows)>0?"Hacker":"No Hacker";
    echo $res;
```

Comment: tried this-> $check = mysql_query("SELECT count(name),name FROM hack_log group by name HAVING count(name)>5");
if($check){
 echo "HACKER!";
}else{
 echo "not hacker";
} 

didn't work, always returns true

Comment: You want to check if you have any user with more than 5 shows ?

Comment: yes, even if I hadn't it supose to echo "not hacker"

Comment: ok, nvm it worked, but how to I return this to use it in the if?

Comment: @Joao Paulo I were edited my answer, you have now two ways to implement it. i suggest you to choose the second way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got this error using the PDO version:

Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'

Comment: @Joao Paulo no problem, change dblib to mysql

Comment: always showing 'No Hacker', and I have more than 5 rows with the same name :(

Comment: @Joao Paulo answer edited, fetch all rows to array and than count array